# Error on loading specific bitmaps for textures on OpenGL ES for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a videogame, and I was testing it on my phone. Recently, I decided to test it on another device, and in this new device I'm having problem with some specific textures, while the rest are going just fine. I have no idea what could be going on, I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work.
If I change the bmp picture for other similar, it loads fine, but when I move back to the original it doesn't load at all.

The code for loading textures that I use is the following: (although I think it's very common and it shouldn't crash...)

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.skybox_frente);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
if(gl instanceof GL11) {
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);
} else {
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
}
gl.glTexEnvx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

bitmap.recycle();
```

The exact error is that BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null, even when the InputStream is NOT null.

EDIT: In fact, the error was on getting the InputStream, `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.skybox_frente)` is returning an empty stream just with specific pictures...

Here is one of the pictures I can't load:

http://www.mediafire.com/?1if0iazmc89file

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Any reason why you don't use BitmapFactory.decodeResource()?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image data in to a byte array and use decodeByteArray of BitmapFactory class.

Loading the image data into a byte array-

```
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(bis.count);
         int current = 0;
         while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte)current);
          }
         byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
```

Then use decodeByteArray of BitmapFactory using "imageData".

```
         BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length)
```

Please let me know if this worked for you or not.

Comment: I get an error on this code, because the field "count" is protected, not public, so I can not get its value...

Comment: Forget about it, I just realized that the error is not on `decodeStream`, but in getting the InputStream. `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.skybox_frente)` is returning an empty stream, just with specific pictures, other work ok. Do you know what the problem ight be? Thanks!